# How to make a gap within a continuous time-series variable between years?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot two time-series data with ggplot2, and add a break on purpose between two years.
Here is the example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
ny=3
n = 365*ny
md = data.frame('Date' = as.Date('2001-01-01') + 1:n -1, 
                'P' = rep(sin(seq(0, pi/2, length.out=365)), ny),
                'ET' = rep(sin(seq(0, pi/2, length.out=365)), ny)*0.8 )

mf = reshape2::melt(md, id='Date')
mf=cbind(mf, 'year' = as.numeric(substr(mf$Date, 1, 4)))


ggplot(data=mf)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=value, color=variable, grouping=year))
```

The line for ET and P are continuous at 12-31 to 01-1 of next year. How to make a gap between them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to replicate the intent is to use facets for the years with different x-scales:

```
ggplot(data=mf)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=value, color=variable, grouping=year)) + 
  facet_grid(.~year, scales = "free_x")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could include or exclude the dates (choose one of the `theme` lines) and `facet_wrap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ny <- 3
n <- 365 * ny
md <- data.frame(
  "Date" = as.Date("2001-01-01") + 1:n - 1,
  "P" = rep(sin(seq(0, pi / 2, length.out = 365)), ny),
  "ET" = rep(sin(seq(0, pi / 2, length.out = 365)), ny) * 0.8
)

mf <- reshape2::melt(md, id = "Date")
mf <- cbind(mf, "year" = as.numeric(substr(mf$Date, 1, 4)))

mf |>
  ggplot(aes(Date, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ year, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") +
  # theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + # Either with dates
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + # Or without dates
  labs(x = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>